How to change automatic title in a plot obtained from the tseriesChaos library
I am using the routine* stplot* for the space-time separation plot from the
*tseriesChaos *library for Analysis of Nonlinear Time Series. My problem is that
the routine puts automatically the title. I would like to have a  the plot without title.
required package
library(tseriesChaos)
data
c(7.99615, 7.984607, 7.965385, 7.938509, 7.904017, 7.861954,
7.812375, 7.755347, 7.690946, 7.619257, 7.540376, 7.454408, 7.361466,
7.261675, 7.155165, 7.042078, 6.922565, 6.796782, 6.664895, 6.527078,
6.383513, 6.234389, 6.079899, 5.920248, 5.755644, 5.5863, 5.412439,
5.234285, 5.052069, 4.866028, 4.676401, 4.483432, 4.287368, 4.088462,
3.886965, 3.683135, 3.477229, 3.269509, 3.060234, 2.849668, 2.638073,
2.425713, 2.21285, 1.999746, 1.786663, 1.57386, 1.361596, 1.150126,
0.939703, 0.730579, 0.523, 0.31721, 0.113449, -0.088049, -0.287051,
-0.483333, -0.676673, -0.866857, -1.053676, -1.236927, -1.416413,
-1.591944, -1.763338, -1.930419, -2.093018, -2.250976, -2.404139,
-2.552364, -2.695512, -2.833457, -2.966079, -3.093266, -3.214918,
-3.330941, -3.44125, -3.545771, -3.644437, -3.737193, -3.823989,
-3.904789, -3.979563, -4.048291, -4.110963, -4.167576, -4.21814,
-4.262669, -4.301191, -4.333739, -4.360357, -4.381096, -4.396017,
-4.405188, -4.408686, -4.406596, -4.39901, -4.386029, -4.367759,
-4.344316, -4.315822, -4.282403)
routine
stplot(data, m=5,d=2,idt=1,mdt=50);

where m is  the embedding dimension, d is the timelag, idt are the
observation steps in each iteration, and  mdt the number of iterations.
Due that this is the first time posting a question I can not upload
the image of the plot with my data, but here I provide a link to a plot from the author
of the routine applied to rossler model:
space-time separation plot
How can I eliminate the title?
I have tried to put  main = NULL inside stplot but it does not work perhaps because
the title is settled by main which is inside the function defined by the author of the library.
Here is the link the code of the routine (tseriesChaos)
Please, I am new in R, I would appreciate any help.
